# Can i create a shared lib which has both shared and static library

Tags: makefile, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I am tryng to create a shared library which internally is linking to many shared lib and a static lib . In my case my shared lib is not including static lib . I want to know what i am trying whether it is correct or i need to convert static lib to shared lib and then do the linking .

I need to know that is there any makefile flag which allow me to add static library along with shared lib .

Please suggest .

Comment: The flags of your post need to be more specific (library...)

Comment: You need to show us how you are performing the link.

Comment: Is there even a way to link without possibly not including static library?

Comment: i am working on AIX machine and i am using -Ldir -llibname option for linking. No i cannot skip this library only other way is to convert it to shared lib but it's a 3rd party lib so i do not have access to source code .

Comment: @wizard: yes, you just need to create one more dll library which will contain the dependent static library.

Comment: I am not working on windows . It's AIX(IBM Unix) platform and i think probably what i am asking here is make file flag to link static library on Unix . I will edit my question to make it more clear .

Comment: A static library mean that you can transform it to either a dynamic library or as an executable (with your code). A dynamic library can (generally) not be converted to as executable or a static library. You can only use it as a dynamic library. Hope this will answer your answer

Comment: i do not agree with your first line if my static library is position dependent then i won't be able to convert it to shared lib since i do not have source code . Please correct me if i am wrong which i do not think so

Comment: To have a better understanding: consider the static library as a package of precompiled source code, (composed of object file) eg: src1.o src2.o ... -> srcs.lib) So you can transform it as you want. after it is part of the linker to tell where the library is
(eg: application -> your_lib.dll -> thirdlib.dll)

Comment: look at my post (I did put an example but for linux)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a library which is dependent of other library (static and dynamic). But you need to integrate the static library part inside your (because this one can not be load dynamically)

```
dependence of your source code:
your_library -> static_library.lib
your_library -> dynamic_library.dll

how you implement can it (to be used by an executable):

your_library.dll (which contain your_library and static_library source code)
dynamic_library.dll (to distribute with your_library.dll)

or

your_library.dll
static_library.dll (to be created from the static_library.lib)
dynamic_library.dll (to distribute with your_library.dll)
```

edit: here may what you are looking for [convert static library to shared library](http://www.tipcache.com/tip/Convert_a_static_library_%28.a%29_to_a_shared_object_%28.so%29_12.html) (it is for linux, but you will have the same for os):

```
.a files are just archives of .o object files, so all you need to do is unpack the archive and repackage them as a shared object (.so)
ar -x mylib.a
gcc -shared *.o -o mylib.so
```